# Breaking lines with lstlisting

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I would like to show a couple of lines from a CSV file using the listings package with `breaklines=true`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{%
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breaklines,
  showspaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
K01980;23S ribosomal RNA;11.79648646;17.54756407;16.55812848;7.070375553;9.904088434;10.33047681;11.34235283;12.84408234
K01977;16S ribosomal RNA;7.433653271;11.21805284;10.47502621;4.555449801;6.223779066;6.547853101;7.12047883;8.056722
K03046;DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta' [EC:2.7.7.6];1.279373326;1.843958244;1.291530419;0.91598316;1.444456949;1.370082994;1.471863596;1.274232464
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The output is not quite satisfactory, though.

[image]

- The break occurs very early, so there is a lot of empty space at the end of the first line and the second line exceeds the available text width. There is no line break in the second line.
- There is a blank line after each line.

I would like to have something like this:

```
K01980;23S ribosomal RNA;11.79648646;17.54756407;16.55812848;
  7.070375553;9.904088434;10.33047681;11.34235283;12.84408234
K01977;16S ribosomal RNA;7.433653271;11.21805284;10.47502621;
  4.555449801;6.223779066;6.547853101;7.12047883;8.056722
K03046;DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit beta' [EC:2.7.7.6];
  1.279373326;1.843958244;1.291530419;0.91598316;1.444456949;
  1.370082994;1.471863596;1.274232464
```

Comment: I would use rather a tabular environment for this than `lstlisting`

Comment: I do that too, but the point here is to show how raw data is represented.

Comment: There is no indication about raw data in your question, however

Comment: I would like to show a couple of lines from a CSV file?

Comment: I think the question is still relevant, as it is obviously not evident how to make `listlistings` break at any character and not only at spaces. Or is it?

Comment: Basically you need to redefine `;` as `;\allowbreak`.

Comment: I gave up on `listings` and switched to `minted`. The `breakafter` option was all I needed.

Answer (score 4):

`listings` doesn't break chunks of charcters when they belong to the same internal category. In this case, the *letter*, *digit* and *other* categories are of special interest. By default, characters are assigned to categories like you would expect, i.e. letters are of category *letter*, digits are *digit*, and symbols are *other*.

When a *letter* is found, all following *letter* or *digit* characters are read until a non-*letter*/non-*digit* is found. This series is then output as one chunk. The same now happens with all characters that are non-*letter* until the next *letter* is found. Processing the input in that way prevents the long series of digits, periods and semicolons in your example from being broken, because no *letter* is found to start a new chunk.

Here are to proposals how to solve this problem:

- Rearrange the character categories such that the built chunks correspond to the logical data units of your specific usecase. For example you might want to move digits and the period also to category *letter*, while leaving the semicolon as category *other*. This can be done by adding

  ```
  alsoletter={0123456789.}
  ```

  to `\lstset`. Line breaks now can occur also after all decimal numbers and after the semicolon.
- More straight forward is to use the `literate` option and redefine the semicolon to a version that allows a linebreak after the symbol:

  ```
  literate={;}{{;\allowbreak}}1
  ```

Both solutions now give the more appealing result

[image]